# What are all the decidable languages that can be constructed using a turing machine with only the Reject and Accept states?

Tags: turing-machines

What languages can be decided by a two-state TM that has two states: one accepting and one rejecting?

As a newbie in TMs, there are some definitions I am not familiar with, of which the answer is obviously dependent,  like:

- Can we draw an outgoing arrow from the Accept or Reject states?
- Can either of these two states be the starting state?

Comment: Why not? The question is in the header. The body are minor questions that matter for a complete answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Please ask only one question per question and use the body to elaborate the question in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only two states, the rejecting state and the accepting state, then the machine must start in one of those states. That means it must immediately halt, which should tell you what language it can accept.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like the languages are: 1. The empty language, 2. The language containing only the empty string. Are any of them decidable?

Comment: One of those languages is correct; the other isn't. And of course they're decidable -- you've found Turing machines that decide them!

Comment: Why arent they both correct? If the starting state is the Reject state then the language will be the empty language. And if the starting state is the Accept state then the language will be the empty string alone. What am I missing?

Comment: In the second case, you're claiming that the machine rejects every input except the empty string. How does it do that?

Comment: O... I see. So is it right that the second language would be $Sigma$*?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.